# Cannot find containers with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a very simple script which will scrape the top 50 sounds on SoundCloud, add them to a dictionary, then save them to a file. When I try to find all the items I get none back (as seen by a debug message I put in). I was wondering what I did wrong and if anyone could help me figure it out, thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
import requests

website = "https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=rock&country=all-countries"
session = requests.session()


def get_songs():
    songs = {}
    response = session.get(website)
    soup = Bs(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.title.text)

containers = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "chartTracks__item"})

if len(containers) == 0:
    print("Could not find any containers")

for element in containers:
    chart_track_div = element.div("chartTrack")
    details_div = chart_track_div.div("chartTrack__details")
    artist = details_div.div("chartTrack__username").text
    song_name = details_div.div("chartTrack__title").text

    songs[song_name] = artist

return songs


def create_file(songs_dictionary):
# Just printing out key&value for now

    for key, value in songs_dictionary:
        print("Song: " + key)
        print("Artist: " + value)


toSave = get_songs()
create_file(toSave)
```

This is what I get after I run it: http://prntscr.com/m78dfr

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I needed to change.

First, it is a dynamic page, so if you want to grab that info into containers using the `soup.find_all("li", {"class": "chartTracks__item"})`, you'd have to render the page first, either with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/), then do the `.find_all`

However, the data you are pulling is found in the html source, but under different tags, so I just went ahead and grabbed the info you were grabbing.

Second, I didn't know if this was exactly your intention, but you were saving artist as the user name, and song as the title. Unfortunately, each of those songs have slightly different formats listed by soundcloud. If you were to truly grab strictly the artist - title, it'll require some filtering and re-working with the strings. But I kept it as you had it, and you can choose what to do from there.

Third, you didn't pass any parameters into your first function:

```
def get_songs():
    songs = {}
    response = session.get(website)
```

So it's not going to do anything, since it's referring to `website`, but it's never passed in. So I changed that to:

```
def get_songs(website):
    songs = {}
    response = session.get(website)
```

Fourth, you can't iterate through the dictionary with `for key, value in songs_dictionary:`. It's asking for 2 values, but can only unpack 1. To do what you are trying, you have 2 options:

```
for key, value in songs_dictionary.items():
        print("Song: " + key)
        print("Artist: " + value)
```

or

```
for key in songs_dictionary:
        print("Song: " + key)
        print("Artist: " + songs_dictionary[key])
```

I think that's all that I found, but full code here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
import requests

website = "https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=rock&country=all-countries"
session = requests.session()


def get_songs(website):
    songs = {}
    response = session.get(website)
    soup = Bs(response.text, "html.parser")

    print(soup.title.text)

    containers = soup.find_all("section", {"class": "sounds"})
    songs_ranks = containers[0].find_all('li')


    if len(songs_ranks) == 0:
        print("Could not find any containers")

    for element in songs_ranks:

        artist = element.find_all('a')[1].text
        song_name = element.find('a', {'itemprop':'url'}).text

        songs[song_name] = artist

    return songs


def create_file(songs_dictionary):
# Just printing out key&value for now

    for key, value in songs_dictionary.items():
        print("Song: " + key)
        print("Artist: " + value)


toSave = get_songs(website)
create_file(toSave)
```

**output:**

```
Song: KING
Artist: XXXTENTACION
Song: Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody
Artist: rizky.rilos
Song: áá
©á·áá
¡á¯ (Brit Rock Remix For áá
¡áá
­áá
¢áá
®á¨áá
¦) - BTS
Artist: BTS
Song: XXXTENTACION - NUMB
Artist: conrad foxx
Song: In The End
Artist: LINKIN_PARK
Song: I Write Sins Not Tragedies
Artist: Panic! At The Disco
Song: Man Upon The Hill
Artist: Stars and Rabbit
Song: Nirvana - Smells like teen spirit
Artist: Rocio Araujo
Song: Nickelback - Rockstar
Artist: Roadrunner USA
Song: xxxtentacion - valentine
Artist: ó  
Song: Zombie
Artist: Bad Wolves
Song: MarÃ­lia MendonÃ§a â Amante NÃ£o Tem Lar
Artist: Sertanejo Repost
Song: sleep thru ur alarms
Artist: Lontalius
Song: Angel With A Shotgun
Artist: NightCore
Song: Nightcore - My Demons
Artist: NightCore
Song: Armada - Harusnya Aku
Artist: DJCantik.com
Song: Dont Stop Me Now - Queen
Artist: Zinay Hernandez
Song: Sing To Me feat. Karen O
Artist: waltermartinmusic
Song: Everytime
Artist: boy pablo
Song: Tongue Tied - Grouplove
Artist: Atlantic Records
Song: For Beginners
Artist: M. Ward
Song: This Is Gospel
Artist: Panic! At The Disco
Song: Skillet - Hero
Artist: Warner Music Nashville
Song: Wonderwall - Oasis
Artist: Florian.N.
Song: High Hopes - Panic! At the disco
Artist: IrisDH
Song: Another One Bites The Dust (Remastered 2011)
Artist: Queen
Song: Panic! At The Disco - Bohemian Rhapsody (from Suicide Squad: The Album) (Audio)
Artist: Panic! At The Disco
Song: Killer Queen (Remastered 2011)
Artist: Queen
Song: Blue Bird-Naruto Shippuden 3rd Opening Theme
Artist: flaviogomes23
Song: Virzha-tentang rindu mp3
Artist: Arjuna Bilal
Song: Tipe-X - Mawar Hitam
Artist: Tora Loaadiing
Song: Lolot - Galungan Lan Kuningan
Artist: I Made Suwita
Song: Red Hot Chili peppers - Californication
Artist: arthyum
Song: Nickelback - How You Remind Me
Artist: Roadrunner USA
Song: 2004 Green Day "Boulevard of broken dreams" Vinyl rip
Artist: Collin CodeÃ¯ne
Song: ZÃ© Neto E Cristiano -  Seu PolÃ­cia (DVD ZÃ© Neto E Cristiano Ao Vivo Em SÃ£o JosÃ© Do Rio Preto)
Artist: Sertanejo universitario (2018)
Song: Pink Floyd - Wish You Were Here
Artist: Ulviyya Ali
Song: Apocalypse
Artist: Cigarettes After Sex
Song: Linkin Park - In The End
Artist: ALLMusic
Song: Come As You Are
Artist: Nirvana
Song: Avenged Sevenfold - Dear God
Artist: Malik Hamza Sajjad
Song: Kaleo - Way Down We Go
Artist: AminAshkan
Song: Ya Qurban, Khumariyaan, Coke Studio Season 11, Episode 7
Artist: CokeStudio
Song: IDOL (Korean classical music ver.)_2018MMA VER.
Artist: Atm Soo
Song: Gym Best Music For Workout vol 2
Artist: Gym Best MusicFor Workout
Song: Do I Wanna Know? - Arctic Monkeys
Artist: Teenage Kicks.
Song: Um44k - Nossa MÃºsica âªâ«
Artist: Portal do Rap
Song: Nanatsu No Taizai (The Seven Deadly Sins) Anime OST - Perfect Time (POWER SONG)
Artist: cobritsa
Song: Tipe X - Genit
Artist: Hilmie CintaSederhana
Song: Kodaline - All I want - Acoustic Performance
Artist: Andy Wells 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out, really appreciate it!

Comment: no worries! play around with with the code a bit too. and if the solution is working out for you, be sure to accept the solution.